# What legal grounds exist to dispute the benefits received by the assignee?

Tags: contract-law, england-and-wales

Let's suppose A provides some type of services to B in exchange for a monthly payment. A assigns the benefit of all payments it is entitled to receive from B, to C, in exchange for £1.

Under what circumstances could either A or B seek to recover any payments made to C by B? Assume the governing law is that of England and Wales.

My understanding..

Recovery by A: Upon A receiving the consideration of £1 from C, I'm assuming there are no legal grounds for A to recover any payments made by B to C.

Recovery by B: I'm assuming there are no legal grounds for B to recover any payments made by B to C, as C has no obligations to B under the agreement between A and B. I'm ignoring clawbacks in the event of insolvency.

If B was to stop making payments to C that were due and payable, I'm assuming only C has the right to take legal action against B for the late payments?

Comment: It is permitted, even encouraged, to answer one's own question on this site. It is better form to do that, rather than including an answer in a question.

Comment: @DavidSiegel The OP is not embedding in the question an answer. For the most part, the latter half of the post is just a conjecture that the OP would like others to validate.

Comment: @IñakiViggers Exactly, that was my intention, to show that I've researched the answer to the question and wasn't merely asking for the answer. Next time I'll try to structure the question and research differently.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> Under what circumstances could either A or B seek to recover any payments made to C by B?

Your rationale about [non-]recovery by A is accurate. It appears that the closest A can get to that is to agree with B to modify the contract in a way that complies with section (2) of the [Contracts (Rights of Third Parties) Act 1999](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1999/31/section/2). But that amendment would not revert or affect payments that B already made to C.

As for recovery  by B, [section 3](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1999/31/section/3)(4) of the Act provides that B "*shall also have available to him [...] by way of counterclaim any matter not arising from the contract that would have been available to him by way of defence or set-off or, as the case may be, by way of counterclaim against the third party if the third party had been a party to the contract*" unless, per subsection (5), an express term of contract excludes that scenario. This suggests that, at least under some circumstances that involve breach of contract, B might obtain recovery from C.

> If B was to stop making payments to C that were due and payable, I'm assuming only C has the right to take legal action against B for the late payments?

Not just C is allowed to take legal action. [Section 4](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1999/31/section/4) of the Act provides that party A, the promisee, retains the right "*to enforce any term of the contract*" short of double recovery (section 5).

Comment: I don’t think the *Contracts (Rights of Third Parties) Act 1999* is relevant. There is no contract here which confers a benefit on a third party; an assignee is not a [third party beneficiary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_party_beneficiary).

Comment: @sjy "*There is no contract here which confers a benefit on a third party*". Yes, there is. The OP describes the contract as B having to make the payments to C, not to A. The OP's subsequent terms "*payments made to C by B*", "*payments made by B to C*", and "*If B was to stop making payments to C*" only reinforce that C is a third party beneficiary.

Comment: The OP is describing the situation post-assignment. The "contract," for the purposes of s 1 of the *Contracts (Rights of Third Parties) Act 1999*, is the original contract between A and B, which did not contemplate the assignment to C, and was not modified as a result of it. C has acquired the right to sue on the contract as an assignee, not a third party beneficiary referred to in the original contract.

Comment: @sjy "*the original contract between A and B, which did not contemplate the assignment to C*". The OP's description of the contract nowhere purports that A's cession of benefits happened *after* A and B entered the contract. Obviously A's cession to C was reflected in the contract because otherwise B would not know that he has to make to C the payments. The distinction you are trying to draw between *assignee* and *third party beneficiary* is too artificial to elude the scope of the Act. Since C is not a party to the contract, his position fits section1 of the Act.

Comment: The distinction between a third party beneficiary contemplated by the terms of a contract, and an assignee of the contract (which must already exist in order to be assigned), is fundamental. We will have to ask the OP to confirm which was intended, but I have treated the OP's use of the legal term "assignee" as decisive.

Comment: I concur with @sjy. The C(RTP)A is not of any relevance here because we're not talking about third party rights. An assignee is not a third party. An assignee effectively steps into the shoes of the original party for the purpose of rights (but not obligations) that the original party had. If C wanted to assert that they were a third party, they would have to either be expressly named as such in the contract, or the contract would have to purport a benefit to them. See [Section 1(1)](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1999/31/section/1). Assignment doesn't have these conditions.

Comment: Also your assertion regarding Section 4 is highly problematic. Again, because we are talking about assignment, not third party rights. What Section 4 is saying is that B has promised something to A under the contract which purports a benefit on C as a *third party*, but the fact that C has a right to enforce it doesn't negate B's right to enforce it.

Comment: @JBentley "*steps into the shoes of the original party*" conveys that there was an amendment of contract. The OP nowhere suggests that the contract was modified so as to have C "stepping into A's shoes". "*the contract would have to purport a benefit to them*". That is what the contract does. In "*the agreement between A and B*", C is neither promisor nor promisee (see s.1(7) of the Act). Similarly, C fits only the definition of *beneficiary* in [Restatement (Second) of Contracts](http://www.oneclubofjusticides.com/p/restatement-second-contracts.html) at §2(4).

Comment: No, you do not (as a general rule - exceptions exist) have to amend a contract to assign rights under it. Amending requires the consent of the other party (either at contract formation or later) while assignment does not (provided you are not attempting to assign *obligations*).

Comment: "That is what the contract does" - nowhere in OP's post does it say that A and B's contract purports a benefit to C. For example, a simple contract for A to provide a service in return for B's payment to A will not in the general case purport benefits on any third party. On the other hand, if B is paying A to deliver a product to C, *then* there is a purported benefit and that is where the C(RTP)A steps in to give C rights. Without a purported benefit or the express mention of C, the C(RtP)A is of no applicability. That is what Section 1(1) is saying.

Comment: I'm not sure what your final link is but it certainly doesn't appear to be English law, nor does it have any bearing on the C(RTP)A.

Comment: @JBentley "*nowhere in OP's post does it say that A and B's contract purports a benefit to C.*" B is to make to C all payments for the services B received from A. Or are you trying to distinguish between compensation [by B] and performance [by A] so as to suggest that only the latter qualifies as benefit and the former does not? If so, that would introduce various unnecessary and fictitious complexities. "*it certainly doesn't appear to be English law.*" The *Restatement* is very common among courts in the US. I brought it up to showcase the conceptual parallelism with s.1(7) of the Act.

Comment: @IñakiViggers You are conflating the benefit which C has after *assignment* with a purported benefit to C under the *original pre-assignment* contract between A and B. It is the latter which needs to exist for the C(RTP)A to be applicable. Post-assignment, the C(RTP)A isn't relevant because C is no longer a third party - they have direct rights under the contract itself.

Comment: @JBentley "*You are conflating the benefit which C has after assignment with a purported benefit to C under the original pre-assignment contract between A and B.*" Ok, you are back again with the term "original" as if the OP ever indicated that the contract was amended. "*C is no longer a third party*". The OP's description is only in terms of "*the agreement between A and B*". The contract between A and C (i.e., all payments from B in exchange for £1) is separate and therefore different from the notion of an "*[amended] agreement between A, B, and C*".

Comment: @IñakiViggers I think we have some crossed wires. The original contract ("X") is the one between A and B in which B makes payments and A provides a service. The second contract ("Y") is between A and C where A assigns the the benefit of the original contract to C in return for £1. C is not a third party to contract X unless contract X purports a benefit on C or he is expressly named in it. After contract Y is agreed, C has rights derived directly from contract X and so is not a third party.

Comment: @JBentley "*C is not a third party to contract X unless contract X purports a benefit on C or he is expressly named in it.*" Obviously C is expressly named in contract X. This is implicit in the OP's terms of "*payments made by B to C*". B would not know he has to make to C the payments if C were not identified in contract X as recipient of those payments. Your assumption that contract Y was entered later than contract X is neither supported in the OP's description nor relevant. A could have foreseen that contract Y was imminent and thus beforehand name C as third party in contract X.

Comment: @IñakiViggers "Obviously C is expressly named in contract X" - that is not obvious at all. If C were already named in contract X as having the right to collect payment from B *then there would be no need for the assignment*. The fact that A *assigned* their rights to C implies that C was not named in contract X. I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what assignment is.

Comment: @JBentley By sticking to a strict interpretation of "assign" (here an *hapax legomenon*), you keep ignoring the OP's *repeated* mentions of payments "*by B to C*" as well as the absence of any amendments to contract X that --if C were not mentioned there already-- would put B on notice to make to C those payments.

Answer (score 3):

The question is a little confusing because it’s unclear why any of the payments should be refunded.

If A has not provided the services, and B wants a refund, then B can sue A for breach of contract. A assigned its right to be paid to C, but it cannot assign its obligations to C (this would be a [novation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novation) rather than an assignment, which would require both B and C’s consent). If C also agreed with A to perform A’s obligations to B (a subcontract), then A could sue C for any damages A was liable to pay B, but B cannot sue C directly.

If A regrets its decision to assign the contract for £1, and wants to recover larger payments made by B to C in discharge of B’s contractual obligations to A, it can’t. A shouldn’t have assigned the benefit of the contract to C.

If B has not paid, B can be sued under the contract which still exists between A and B. C can file this claim as assignee of the contract. While A could also potentially file the claim, it would be inconsistent with the assignment for A to receive any benefit from it, which would be held on constructive trust for C.

Comment: "*which would require B’s consent*". But more important is that it would require also C's consent, who is unlikely to accept additional obligations for free. "*even though B may not be aware of the assignment.*" That is inconsistent with the OP's repeated mentions of "*payments made by B to C*". A presumption that maybe B thought of C as merely a cashier on behalf of party *A* would be at odds with the substance of the OP's description. "*it would fail if the assignment to C was found out*". Section 4 of the Contracts *Rights of Third Parties) Act 1999* provides the exact opposite.

Comment: I have updated the answer to reflect that B is aware of the assignment (and has apparently agreed with A to discharge its obligations by paying C directly). I have still assumed that the contract was assigned to C, and there was no novation (which as you point out, would require the consent of all three). I have explained why I do not think the *Contracts (Rights of Third Parties) Act 1999* is applicable elsewhere.